# How to make exact comparision in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Consider following query

```
SELECT 
    ('foo' + 1 - 1) = 'foo',
    ('foo' + 1 - 1),
    'foo'
```

to my surprise it returns `1, 0, 'foo'`

so how `0` equals `foo`?

and how to make statement that `('foo' + 1 - 1) = 'foo'` will return false (0) ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: `select 0='foo' -- 1` ... `select '7'+1+2  -- 10` ... `select 'foo'+0 -- 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found one solution

```
SELECT 
    binary ('foo' + 1 - 1) = binary 'foo',
    ('foo' + 1 - 1),
    'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is described in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) section of the mysql documentation.

('foo' + 1 - 1)  expression is evaluated as number because of the numbers and type of operators in the expression. In this context the string 'foo' is interpreted as 0. So, the above expression translates as 0+1-1 => 0. Then, this number is compared with the string 'foo'. Since one of the operands is an integer, the other is a string, the comparison is done as floating point numbers. In this context the string 'foo' is converted to 0. 0 = 0 is true, so you get 1 as a result.